# App disappears when I deploy onto CloudBees with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cloudbees

I am on the free tier of CloudBees.  I want to deploy a simple Clojure web app.

First, I create the app in CloudBees' app manager.  Once I do this, everything looks fine in the server logs.  I see the default application come up, and I can browse to it.

Then I try to deploy my own code from IntelliJ.  When I do, IntelliJ makes the connection to CloudBees successfully, and sits around for about 5--10 seconds.  Then it says that a server-side error occurred, and I should check server logs.

When I go to check the logs, I find that the app is no more.  It's as if IntelliJ deleted it.  I am able to re-create it with the same name.  I've tried this several times, with the same result.

How can I get more visibility into what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look into the IntelliJ logs for the cloudbees plugin (I am not sure who provides that plugin) - to see how it is deleting it.

Deleting on cloudbees is an explicit action - so it must be doing something very strange. I would suggest using the CloudBees CLI to deploy the app (is it a war app?)